# Next13 not working with existing firebase auth context

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, react-context, next-auth

I am building an app using next13 (to make use of server side components), however, for some reason my existing AuthContext is not working. I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: React.createContext is not a function
```

From what I can see, the AuthContext needs to be set to `'use client'`, as there is use of `useState` and `useEffect` within it, but for some reason the application no longer recognises that `createContext` is actually a function.

This is my AuthContext:

```
'use client';

import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { onAuthStateChanged, signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../config';

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setLoading(true);
      setUser(user ?? null);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    setUser(null);
    await signOut(auth)
  };

  const register = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      const userCred = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      await userCred.user.sendEmailVerification({
        url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return {
        errorCode,
        errorMessage
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, loading, login, logout, register }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The AuthContext is then used in my main layout page within the app directory:

```
'use client';

import { CssBaseline, Container } from '@mui/material';
import { NavBar, Footer } from '../components';
import { AuthContextProvider } from '../context';
import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/700.css';


const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <AuthContextProvider>
          <CssBaseline />
          <NavBar />
          <Container component='main' sx={{ padding: 3 }}>
            {children}
          </Container>
          <Footer />
        </AuthContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default RootLayout;
```

I am unsure if I need to take a different approach to authentication, perhaps using the `next-auth` package, but I am not sure what the best way would be.

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of useContext I am using on my application.

```js
'use client'

import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getAuth, User } from 'firebase/auth'
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from 'firebase/app'
import nookies from 'nookies'

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
}

getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const auth = getAuth()

const AuthContext = createContext<User | null>(null)

export function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {
  //
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    return auth.onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        setUser(null)
        nookies.set(undefined, 'token', '', { path: '/' })
      } else {
        const token = await user.getIdToken()
        setUser(user)
        nookies.set(undefined, 'token', token, { path: '/' })
      }
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = setInterval(async () => {
      const user = auth.currentUser
      if (user) await user.getIdToken(true)
    }, 15 * 60 * 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(handle)
  }, [])

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Note that we're also forcing token refresh every 15 minutes, and saving that to cookies. You can access cookies in server pages using the new next13 cookies package.

You can also get the user by importing the useAuth hook we just created.
For example

```js
'use client'
import useAuth from '../context/AuthProvider'

const Page = () => {
const {user} = useAuth()

// Rest of your application
}
```

Hope it helps